# How can I correct imprecisions of trigonometric functions in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the area of a polygone with 200 sides with Monte Carlo method. I know my code is correct (this one is just an example for a triangle), but it is very imprecise due to the error of Java in calculating the Math.cos function. Does anybody know how to fix it without using extra classes (I haven't studied Object Orientated Java yet)? Or just tell me how big the error is? So that I don't have to put sum>359 at the end? Thank you very much for your help...

```
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class polygon {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Random ran = new Random();    
        Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);

        int side=3;
        double dentro = 0; 
        double fuori = 0; 

        double x [] = {3,4,5};
        double y [] = {1,6,3};
        double lengthtopoint[]=new double [side];
        double sidelength[]=new double [side];
        double angles[]=new double [side];

        for (int s =0; s< 1000000; s++){
            double xcheck = ran.nextDouble()*10; 
            double ycheck = ran.nextDouble()*10; 

            for(int i=0;i<side;i++) {
                lengthtopoint[i]=Math.sqrt(((x[i]-xcheck)*(x[i]-xcheck))+((y[i]-ycheck)*(y[i]-ycheck)));


            }

            for(int k=0;k<side-1;k++) {   
                sidelength[k]=Math.sqrt(((x[k+1]-x[k])*(x[k+1]-x[k]))+((y[k+1]-y[k])*(y[k+1]-y[k])));

            }

            sidelength[side-1]=Math.sqrt(((x[0]-x[side-1])*(x[0]-x[side-1]))+((y[0]-y[side-1])*(y[0]-y[side-1])));

            for(int l=0;l<side-1;l++) {
                angles[l] =((180/(Math.PI)))*Math.acos(((lengthtopoint[l]*lengthtopoint[l])+(lengthtopoint[l+1]*lengthtopoint[l+1])-(sidelength[l]*sidelength[l]))/(2*lengthtopoint[l]*lengthtopoint[l+1]));

            }

            angles[side-1] =((180/(Math.PI)))*Math.acos(((lengthtopoint[side-1]*lengthtopoint[side-1])+(lengthtopoint[0]*lengthtopoint[0])-(sidelength[side-1]*sidelength[side-1]))/(2*lengthtopoint[side-1]*lengthtopoint[0]));    


            double sum=0;
            for(int m=0;m<side;m++) {
                sum=sum+angles[m];
            }


            if (sum>359) {
                dentro = dentro+1;    
            } else {
                 fuori = fuori + 1; 
            }
        }

        double Area = (dentro*100/(dentro+fuori));
        System.out.println(Area);  
    }
}
```

Comment: In this form, this question suits [codereview.se] much better. Please consider [edit]ing your question so it matches [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: "due to the error of Java in calculating the Math.cos function" --- what would that error be?

Comment: It is far less likely that Java has had a fundamental mathematical error which has gone unnoticed for twenty years, than it is that you have an error in your code. If you really think a math function is in error, write a short program that demonstrates it, and include that code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sum>359)
```

Replace to `if (sum > 180)`

If you calculate everything with infinite precision, you'll get a number in form k * 360. If you don't then you should round it to the nearest number, divisible by 360. In case you get 358 you program considers is at 0, though it must be 360 as well.